# Can't debug VB5 project

Tags: debugging, vb5

I am suppose to make changes to one of the very old software that my co. sales. Its a VB5 project.

Just to be clear I CANT change language and must ABSOLUTLY use VB5.... (If I could change to C# I would be the happiest man on earth right now.)

Here is the problem.

I installed Microsoft Visual Basic IDE and loaded the .VBP file in.

I read the code to know what part does what but I would like to see it on screen step by step (Debug mode with breakpoints).

So, I punch in some breakpoints and hit "play" (debug button) but I got this error

```
Execution error '-2147024894 (80070002)': Automation Error
```

But curiously the soft work fine when I use the .exe I think it might be a problem with the debugger.

From here I have three options:

```
1-End program
```

It end the program

```
2-Debug
```

It send me to a line of code but I dont know what is the error.

Here is the code it point me on:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
Dim strLangue As String

bBusy = False

Set gImgBackground = Me.imgBackground

Set gBackGround1 = LoadPicture(App.Path & "\images\bg1.gif")
Set gBackGround2 = LoadPicture(App.Path & "\images\bg2.gif")
Me.BackColor = &HC0E0E0
gIniPath = App.Path & "\posi1000.ini"

basMain.gLangFile = App.Path & "\" & inireadvalue(gIniPath, "general", "langfile", "")
If InStr(UCase(basMain.gLangFile), "FR") <> 0 Then
  strLangue = "FR"
ElseIf InStr(UCase(basMain.gLangFile), "EN") <> 0 Then
  strLangue = "EN"
Else
  strLangue = "FR"
End If

strComType = UCase(inireadvalue(gIniPath, "general", "ComType", "MOELLER"))
If strComType = "MOELLER" Then

'    Dim tJRT_COM As JRT_COM.TEST_MOELLER
'    Set tJRT_COM = New JRT_COM.TEST_MOELLER
'    Set tJRT_COM = New JRT_SUCOMA.JRT_SUCOMA

'    Call tJRT_COM.openComDevice("COM1:19200", 0)
'    Set Module1.MyJRT_COM = tJRT_COM


''    Dim t As String

''    Set tJRT_COM = JRT_COM.New(True)
'        Set MyJRT_COM = CreateObject("JRT_SUCOMA.JRT_SUCOMA")
'MyJRT_COM = Ctype(
'    Set MyJRT_COM = New JRT_SUCOMA.JRT_SUCOMA
''    Dim tJRT_COM As New JRT_SUCOMA.JRT_SUCOMA
'

''    Set tJRT_COM = Nothing
'
''    If Module1.MyJRT_COM.setComDevice(gComDevice, strLangue) = 0 Then
''        Module1.MyJRT_COM.
''    End If
'
ElseIf strComType = "OMRON" Then
'    Set MyJRT_COM = New JRT_COM.JRT_OMRON
'    Set MyJRT_COM = CreateObject("JRT_COM.TEST_OMRON")
'    Set MyJRT_COM = MyJRT_COM_MOELLER
''  Else
''    Set MyJRT_COM = New JRT_COM.JRT_MOELLER
''    Set MyJRT_COM = CreateObject("JRT_COM.TEST_MOELLER")
End If

gOfflineMode = inireadvalue(gIniPath, "General", "OfflineMode", "0")

gComDevice = inireadvalue(gIniPath, "General", "ComDevice", "Com1:19200")
If inireadvalue(gIniPath, "General", "ShowSelectComDevice", "0") = "1" Then
  If strComType = "MOELLER" Then
    bBusy = True
    If Module1.MyJRT_COM_MOELLER.SetComDevice(gComDevice, strLangue) = 0 Then
      Call iniwritevalue(gIniPath, "General", "ComDevice", gComDevice)
    End If
    bBusy = False
ElseIf strComType = "OMRON" Then
    bBusy = True
**********It point here**************************************************************
->    If Module1.MyJRT_COM_OMRON.SetComDevice(gComDevice, strLangue) = 0 Then
      Call iniwritevalue(gIniPath, "General", "ComDevice", gComDevice)
    End If
     bBusy = False
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

Just so you know I haven't write that code I am only doing some mod work.

Third option:

```
3-Help
```

It gives me another error

```
Cannot find the windows help.
```

What do I do??? Does anyone had that problem before ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it! I had two dependencies "hard coded" in the vb project that would try to load two .dll on the wrong path even if I would browse Microsoft VB IDE to the right file. I had to place those file in the path specified by Microsoft VB5. And problem solve.